# Compton scattering from moving frame

Tags: special-relativity, photons, scattering

How does an observer see a Compton Scattering from a reference frame moving with constant speed $\vec{v}$ in the photon direction? (Assuming electron is at rest in the lab frame)

Comment: What does electron do in the observer frame?

Comment: I guess it moves with speed v in the opposite direction